# Why is my stepwise regression causing a shorter output?

Tags: regression, glm, predict

I'm trying to run a stepwise regression but the output that I'm getting is shorter than the input data frame. I can't share my data unfortunately but any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
#training data
a3<-na.omit(train_occur)
sum(is.na(train_occur))
> 0
dim(a3)
>2228   10    
full_log<-glm(formula = occurrence ~ . , family=binomial(link=logit), data= train_occur, control = list(maxit = 50))
back_log_occur<-step(full_log)
length(back_log_occur$fitted.values)
>66
#test data
dim(test_occur) #I took out the response variable although I found it doesn't seem to matter whether or not the response variable is there...
>243   9
pred_back_log_occur<-predict(object=back_log_occur,data=test_occur,type="response")
length(pred_back_log_occur)
> 66
```

I expected 2228 fitted values for the training and 243 predicted values for the test set.

Comment: do you have complete data for all of your input variables? or are there `na` values?

Comment: Hi @Simon, I checked for NA variables in the training set with this line of code  `sum(is.na(train_occur))`  so I'm pretty sure there's no NA.

Comment: ah sorry I missed that. I cant replicate this using a test dataset so its probably something specific to your data. do you get the same problem when you try the code on a standard dataset (e.g. iris, mtcars...)?

Comment: @Simon - thanks again! I tried with a standard dataset (mtcars) and it's working the way I expect. It must be in my dataset then--do you have any suggestions on what I might look for? (Sorry-can't seem to make line breaks)  `dim(mtcars) #32 11 
car_data<-mtcars[,c(1:4,8)]
dim(car_data) #32 5
train_car<-car_data[1:30,] 
test_car<-car_data[31:32,]
car1<-glm(formula = vs ~ mpg + cyl + disp + hp, family=binomial(link=logit), data= train_car, control = list(maxit = 50))
back_cars<-step(car1)
length(back_cars$fitted.values) #30 
car_pred<-predict(car1,test_car) 
length(car_pred) #2
 `